# Conditional Formatting Not Working on Cells with Formula

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I can't get this to work. 
Before, the cells I selected will highlight RED if the cell contains a number >5. But now that I entered a formula in the cells, conditional formatting doesn't work.

The formula I added is:

```
=IF(F135>0,$D$2-F135,"Not Received")
```

Basically, **what I want is if the result is >5, it gets highlighted RED**.

Please help.

Comment: Which cell are you applying this too?

Comment: I'm applying the conditional formatting on cells that contain the formula I mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on where you want this you can use formula such as

```
AND(ISNUMBER(H135),H135>5)
```

[image: Formula]

Comment: That works, but it highlights all other cells that contain text, such as "Not Received" which is part of the formula.

Comment: Changr to =AND(ISNUMBER(H135),H135>5)

Comment: @Beginner1 If you got a way to do this, can you please post here? I am in same boat now. All other cells with simply values are getting formatted but the cells with formulas are not getting formatted.